# jQuery Code is only working when pasted in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this function for a Mobile Font markup switch, its working in the console, but not when i run it over document ready function or call the function in the console.

i have to paste code in the console.

no error messages.. weird thing.

any solutions or tips maybe ?

I am not able to send html code because this is a project for a customer.

please understand this.

```
var d = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)");
    menu_to_mobile(d)
    d.addListener(menu_to_mobile)

    function menu_to_mobile() {
        if(d.matches) {
          var menu_points = $('li.dynamic-font-menu');
          var bullet_points = $('div.dynamic-bullet-points');

            $('div.navigation-overlay').remove();
            $('div.mobile-button').load('menu-trigger-mobile.html');
            loadmobile_menu();

            setTimeout(()=>{
              if ($('anchor-point-1').hasClass('mobile-anchor-point-1')) {
                $('anchor-point-2').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-2');
                $('anchor-point-3').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-3');
                $('anchor-point-4').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-4');
                $(menu_points[0]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-Bold');
                $(menu_points[1]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
                $(menu_points[2]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
                $(menu_points[3]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');

                $(bullet_points[0]).addClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[1]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[2]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[3]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            }

            if ($('anchor-point-2').hasClass('mobile-anchor-point-2')) {
                $('anchor-point-1').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-1');
                $('anchor-point-3').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-3');
                $('anchor-point-4').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-4');

                $(menu_points[0]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
                $(menu_points[1]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-Bold');
                $(menu_points[2]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
                $(menu_points[3]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');

                $(bullet_points[1]).addClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[0]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[2]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[3]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            }

            if ($('anchor-point-3').hasClass('mobile-anchor-point-3')) {
                $('anchor-point-1').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-1');
                $('anchor-point-2').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-2');
                $('anchor-point-4').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-4');

                $(menu_points[0]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
                $(menu_points[1]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
                $(menu_points[2]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-Bold');
                $(menu_points[3]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');

                $(bullet_points[2]).addClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[0]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[1]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[3]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');

            }

            if ($('anchor-point-4').hasClass('mobile-anchor-point-4')) {

                $('anchor-point-1').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-1');
                $('anchor-point-2').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-2');
                $('anchor-point-3').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-3');

                $(menu_points[1]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
                $(menu_points[3]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-Bold');
                $(menu_points[2]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
                $(menu_points[0]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');

                $(bullet_points[3]).addClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[0]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[1]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
                $(bullet_points[2]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            }
        } , 500)


        }
    }
```

Comment: Things to consider: menu_to_mobile is a function without arguments and you send it "d" on menu_to_mobile(d). 2- Are you using an external js file? If your not getting errors in your console when loading this code, might be because its never loaded.

Comment: The code should work because i added a alert('works'); and it pops up, but the if statements are beeing ignored.. this is tilting me right now

Comment: Have you done 'console.log(d.matches)' before the first if? What does it output?  Or are the if's inside setTimeout not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your this script in the head, you might want to move it to after the entire body.
Dosen't Work:

```
<head>
<script src="doDOM.js"></script>
</head>
```

Works:

```
<body>
<h1>HI!</h1>
<script src="doDOM.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your javascript is getting executed before DOM is ready. Which means your html elements are not ready. So jQuery will fail to find html element and eventually it will not work. It's working in console because your DOM is ready and then you are executing JS code on it. Answer from @N8Javascript will also solve your problem.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {   
var d = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)");
menu_to_mobile(d)
d.addListener(menu_to_mobile)

function menu_to_mobile() {
    if(d.matches) {
      var menu_points = $('li.dynamic-font-menu');
      var bullet_points = $('div.dynamic-bullet-points');

        $('div.navigation-overlay').remove();
        $('div.mobile-button').load('menu-trigger-mobile.html');
        loadmobile_menu();

        setTimeout(()=>{
          if ($('anchor-point-1').hasClass('mobile-anchor-point-1')) {
            $('anchor-point-2').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-2');
            $('anchor-point-3').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-3');
            $('anchor-point-4').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-4');
            $(menu_points[0]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-Bold');
            $(menu_points[1]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
            $(menu_points[2]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
            $(menu_points[3]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');

            $(bullet_points[0]).addClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[1]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[2]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[3]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
        }

        if ($('anchor-point-2').hasClass('mobile-anchor-point-2')) {
            $('anchor-point-1').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-1');
            $('anchor-point-3').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-3');
            $('anchor-point-4').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-4');

            $(menu_points[0]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
            $(menu_points[1]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-Bold');
            $(menu_points[2]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
            $(menu_points[3]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');

            $(bullet_points[1]).addClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[0]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[2]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[3]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
        }

        if ($('anchor-point-3').hasClass('mobile-anchor-point-3')) {
            $('anchor-point-1').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-1');
            $('anchor-point-2').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-2');
            $('anchor-point-4').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-4');

            $(menu_points[0]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
            $(menu_points[1]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
            $(menu_points[2]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-Bold');
            $(menu_points[3]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');

            $(bullet_points[2]).addClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[0]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[1]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[3]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');

        }

        if ($('anchor-point-4').hasClass('mobile-anchor-point-4')) {

            $('anchor-point-1').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-1');
            $('anchor-point-2').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-2');
            $('anchor-point-3').removeClass('mobile-anchor-point-3');

            $(menu_points[1]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
            $(menu_points[3]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-Bold');
            $(menu_points[2]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');
            $(menu_points[0]).css('font-family', 'TTFirsNeue-LightItalic');

            $(bullet_points[3]).addClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[0]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[1]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
            $(bullet_points[2]).removeClass('dynamic-bullet-points-active');
        }
    } , 500)


    }
}
});
```